# Table to get all the metadata modified by a user

Tags: soql, metadata-api

i am not familiar with the salesforce schema. Is there a table where i can query to get the list of things modified by a user in a salesforce org?

Something like:

```
select metadataName from TABLE where lastModifiedDate = 'Today' and lastModifiedBy = 'user_X';
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Edit: Removed erroneous information.

There's actually an object called [SetupAuditTrail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm) that you can query directly to find all changes made by a user. Note that there are some limits to what you can do (e.g. aggregate queries), but provides the same details as you'd get when downloading the View Setup Audit Trail details. You can also query specific objects using the Tooling API (e.g. CustomField) to determine changes across specific metadata types. Both types of queries can be executed directly from the Developer Console, but other tools, such as the Apex Data Loader, may not support Tooling API queries.

Comment: is there a table that stores the Audit trail? i am trying to pull things out using code and avoid manual/excel based work

Comment: @OK999 I actually double-checked, and realized there is a way to query the Audit Trail. Added more info.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below .

`SELECT Action,CreatedById,CreatedDate,DelegateUser,Display,Id,ResponsibleNamespacePrefix Section FROM SetupAuditTrail`